# Open/Run File With a C++ Program

Tags: c++, file

How can you Open/Run a file with a C++ Program, not like reading and writing to a file, but *right click on file *Open/Run with (Insert C++ Program Name Here)? I need this for a simple scripting language that I am building.

Thank You for any help!

Comment: That has nothing to do with what language you use to implement your tool, but everything to do with how to register file handlers in Windows, OS X, KDE, whatever. See for example https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd758090(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @JesperJuhl Doesn't it have relevance in if a program is prepared to collect a file as input? That would be language specific in implementation.

Comment: No, the filename will be passed on the command line, the exact syntax/parameter is up to you when registering the file handler with the shell.

Comment: @FBergo, Ohh, Thank you! That makes sense!